# Slow deleting message from AWS SQS queue

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Problem:

> I have SQS queue with default settings.

9  consumers pulling messages,  with concurrency: 100. 
As a result, 90% time all work with massage, was spent on removing it from the SQS.
There are 2 million messages in queue sometimes.

> info - TIME all58189132: 7s 25.336044ms
>   info - TIME delMessage58189132: 7s 3.667635ms
>
> info - TIME all58189132: 7s 25.336044ms
>   info - TIME delMessage90392602: 6s 943.837946ms
>
> info - TIME all90392602: 6s 966.396512ms
>   info - TIME delMessage90392602: 6s 943.837946ms

How can i do it faster?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. What makes you think that "90% time all work with massage, was spent on removing it from the SQS"? Can you please explain how your workers are processing the messages? For example, how are they deleting the messages?

Comment: you can see time, for all work with message spending about 7 seconds.
Deleted message 6.8 seconds. For deleting message from queue we using
 function from AWS SDK

 `var params = {
  QueueUrl: 'STRING_VALUE',

  ReceiptHandle: 'STRING_VALUE' /* required */
};
sqs.deleteMessage(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); 
  else     console.log(data);           
});
`

Comment: How are the above timings related to the code you have shown? I cannot see the statements that are generating your timing statements. (By the way, you can Edit your question to insert code.)

Answer (score -1):

Basically message-based flow is:

1. Poll/Listen for the message
2. Receive message
3. Do work
4. Delete message

You have to do all of the above steps. You can not skip any one step.
Simply you need to increase the number of consumers.

Note: Increase consumers only when you cannot afford this much execution time. Else, let them take whatever time they are taking.

Comment: i do all this step, off course. I show timing. all work with message and only deleting message. Example: all: 7s 25.336044ms and deleting: 7s 3.667635ms. I have 9 consumers with concurrency 100. In one moment we worked with 900 messages, you think i can increase consumers?

Comment: As I said, increase consumers only when you want your work to be done fast.

But, this will increase your cost. As, you will be calling more poll calls to SQS. And, there may be time when there is no message, or less messages. And, you still running with 100 of consumers. So, there is a trade off for each approach.
For saving cost, you should think of increasing "Receive Message Wait Time" to 20. Default value is zero.